# Unable to add rows to table using table.addrow

Tags: javascript, html-table

I am trying to add rows to a html table, but it isn't working.

```
    $('#listTimes .timesList').html('\
      <table class="timesTable">\
        <tr>\
          <th>No.</th>\
          <th>Time</th>\
          <th>Avg. of 5</th>\
        </tr>\
      </table>');
    var table = $('#listTimes table');
    //Some code
    var row = table.insertRow();//This is where the error occurs
```

When I run this code, I get the following errors:

```
    Uncaught TypeError: table.insertRow is not a function
        at saveTimes.js:44
        at DataSnapshot.js:126
        at e.inorderTraversal (SortedMap.js:170)
        at e.inorderTraversal (SortedMap.js:169)
        at e.inorderTraversal (SortedMap.js:169)
        at e.inorderTraversal (SortedMap.js:169)
        at e.inorderTraversal (SortedMap.js:169)
        at e.inorderTraversal (SortedMap.js:169)
        at e.inorderTraversal (SortedMap.js:169)
        at e.inorderTraversal (SortedMap.js:169)
    (anonymous) @ saveTimes.js:44
    (anonymous) @ DataSnapshot.js:126
    e.inorderTraversal @ SortedMap.js:170
    e.inorderTraversal @ SortedMap.js:169
    e.inorderTraversal @ SortedMap.js:169
    e.inorderTraversal @ SortedMap.js:169
    e.inorderTraversal @ SortedMap.js:169
    e.inorderTraversal @ SortedMap.js:169
    e.inorderTraversal @ SortedMap.js:169
    e.inorderTraversal @ SortedMap.js:169
    e.inorderTraversal @ SortedMap.js:169
    e.inorderTraversal @ SortedMap.js:169
    e.inorderTraversal @ SortedMap.js:618
    e.forEachChild @ ChildrenNode.js:287
    e.forEach @ DataSnapshot.js:125
    (anonymous) @ saveTimes.js:34
    (anonymous) @ EventRegistration.js:65
    t.exceptionGuard @ util.js:556
    e.raise @ EventQueue.js:158
    e.si @ EventQueue.js:111
    e.raiseEventsForChangedPath @ EventQueue.js:95
    e.ee @ Repo.js:200
    t.It @ PersistentConnection.js:458
    t.wt @ PersistentConnection.js:452
    e.wt @ Connection.js:262
    e.sn @ Connection.js:256
    (anonymous) @ Connection.js:157
    t.xn @ WebSocketConnection.js:197
    t.handleIncomingFrame @ WebSocketConnection.js:247
    mySock.onmessage @ WebSocketConnection.js:144
    setTimeout (async)
    t.exceptionGuard @ util.js:560
    e.raise @ EventQueue.js:158
    e.si @ EventQueue.js:111
    e.raiseEventsForChangedPath @ EventQueue.js:95
    e.ee @ Repo.js:200
    t.It @ PersistentConnection.js:458
    t.wt @ PersistentConnection.js:452
    e.wt @ Connection.js:262
    e.sn @ Connection.js:256
    (anonymous) @ Connection.js:157
    t.xn @ WebSocketConnection.js:197
    t.handleIncomingFrame @ WebSocketConnection.js:247
    mySock.onmessage @ WebSocketConnection.js:144
```

Answer (score 0):

imho insertRow is not a jquery function. This is why you recieve this error.

```
$(".timesTable > tbody").append("<tr><td>row content</td></tr>");
```

this should do the job.

Comment: However, even if I do `var table = document.getElementById('listTimes').getElementsByClassName('timesTable');` it isn't working...

Answer (score 0):

you can try this :

```js
    $('#listTimes .timesList').html('\
      <table class="timesTable">\
        <tr>\
          <th>No.</th>\
          <th>Time</th>\
          <th>Avg. of 5</th>\
        </tr>\
      </table>');
    var table = $('#listTimes table');
    //Some code
    $(".timesList").html(table);
$(".timesTable > tbody").append("<tr><td>content1</td><td>content2</td><td>content3</td></tr>");
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="listTimes">
  <div class="timesList">
</div>
```